# React cannot update state quick enough

Tags: reactjs

I think due to React's useState asynchronous nature, I am running into an issue where when I try to update the state quickly it does not work. I know of course I am doing something wrong, but not sure what. Basically I have a component that when it loads, might fire off a callback in rapid succession, in this case two times. This should update the state of the parent component by appending to the array in the state system. But it fails. I understand why it fails, but not what I am doing wrong.

```
export const Foo = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

    const onSomeFastAction = (value: any) => {
        console.log(`adding ${value} to selected`)
        console.log(selected) // Prints [] on first AND second logs
        setSelected([...selected, value])
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Only the second value is ever in the array and this only logs once
        console.log(selected);
    }, [selected])

    return (
        <CrazyFastComponentThing
            onThingThatHappens={onSomeFastAction}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a function to set newState:

```
export const Foo = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

    const onSomeFastAction = (value: any) => {
        console.log(`adding ${value} to selected`)
        console.log(selected) // Prints [] on first AND second logs
        setSelected(prevState => {
            const newState = [...prevState];
            newState.push(value);
            return newState;
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Only the second value is ever in the array and this only logs once
        console.log(selected);
    }, [selected])

    return (
        <CrazyFastComponentThing
            onThingThatHappens={onSomeFastAction}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this apply to just appending to arrays? What about removing from an array, and what about objects?

Comment: for remove from array you must send the index of array and in function : `function remove = (index) => { setSelected(prevState => {const newState = [...prevState]; newState.splice(index, 1); return newState; }});`

Comment: for add to object you must send the key and value :  `function remove = (key, value) => { setSelected(prevState => { const newState = {...prevState, key: value}; return newState;}); }`